# Is there any way I could call a subclass method in an ArrayList of a superclass?

Tags: java, oop

I've been trying to write a program where I place animals in an ArrayList of animals and there would be cows, chickens and pigs. The issue that I'm having is that I cant call any method of the subclasses I enter. How could I do this without making an ArrayList of every animal? Thanks in advance!

```
public abstract class Animal{
    protected Boolean feeding = false, walking = false, sleeping = false;
    
    public abstract boolean feed();
    public abstract boolean sleep();
    public abstract boolean walk();
}
```

```
public class Pig extends Animal {
    private boolean clean = false;
    
    public Pig() {
        super();
    }
    
    public boolean cleanUp() {
        return clean = true;
    }
    
    public boolean feed() {
        return feeding = true;
    }

    public boolean sleep() {
        return sleeping = true;
    }

    public boolean walk() {
        return walking = true;
    }

}
```

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        ArrayList<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<Animal>();
        Pig pig = new Pig();
        animals.add(pig);
        
        // this line wont work
        animals.get(0).cleanUp();
        
    }
}
```

Comment: You could cast it if you're certain you know the type: `((Pig)animals.get(0)).cleanUp();`

Comment: You can cast the variable, but it sounds like your design is not good. If you want to have a `cleanup` method, you should probably define it for all `Animal`s.

Comment: Or better yet, define the situation in which these methods are being called. If there's a finalizer type of thing going on, define that for Animal, and have it call cleanUp for Pig.

Comment: Note: while it may work, generally you should not return a variable assignment

Comment: Great thanks for your answers! I will try making an ArrayList for every type of animal as I didn't learn how to use cleanUp function in my class

Comment: The best way to do that is to have cleanUp() as abstract method in `Animal`. Pigs do not clean up after themselves, I reckon :) For animals who don't, you should use `throw new NotImplementedException`.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do it. You declared your list as a list of type `Animal`, this type doesn't have `cleanUp` method.

You could achieve what you want by type-casting, but you need to make sure it's the right class first:

```
  Animal animal = animals.get(0);
  if (animal instanceof Pig) {
    ((Pig) animal).cleanUp();
  }
```

Strictly speaking you don't have to make sure, but believe me: you do.

Comment: Ok, so to achieve what I want I should make an arrayList for every animal or use cleanUp function right?

Comment: You check for type with `instanceof` for each of your animals and do whatever suits the type, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

This is why this code does not compile for Generics

```
List<? extends Animal> animals = new ArrayList<Pig>(); //COMPILES WITH A WARNING
Pig pig = new Pig();
animals.add(pig); //DOES NOT COMPILE
```

Which is exactly what you were trying to do. You are putting in a subclass object in a generic list that declares its super class. Java is being proactive because of type erosion. So you have to do explicit casting for this to work. But the design is wrong because you can create a Dog that extends Animal and it will still enter your animals list. So now you have a list full of elements of different objects and due to polymorphism, the methods available during run time is fluid.

I will suggest you create a concrete cleanUp() method on the super class that is general in nature which can be inherited and used as is, or overridden on specific use cases ie if you must have a list of type Animal.